# Ensure sequential state update when using RXJava scan operator

Tags: android, redux, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I'm trying to implement redux state update pattern using RXJava

```
val subject=PublishSubject.create()
val subject1=PublishSubject.create()

// multiple threads posting 
// on subject and subject1 here. Concurrently 


subject.mergeWith(subject1)
       .scan(
             getInitState(),
             {state, event ->
               // state update here 
             }
         )
        .subscribe({state ->
          // use state here
        })
```

As you can see, I'm using `scan` operator to maintain the state.

How can I be sure that the state updates happen sequentially even when multiple threads are producing events?

Is there some mechanism in `scan` operator which makes the events stand in some queue while waiting for current state update function to finish?

**What I have done:**

I have successfully implemented this pattern in Android environment. It's really easy because if you always do the state update in

`AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

And make state object immutable you are guaranteed to have atomic and sequential state update. But what happens if you don't have dedicated scheduler for state updates? What if you are not on Android?

**What I have researched:**

- I have read the source code for `scan` operator and there is no
  waiting "queue" involved. Just simple state update and emission
- I have also read SerializedSubject source code. There indeed is a waiting queue which serializes emissions. But what happens if I have two subjects? Serializing both of them doesn't mean that they don't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force execution on a single thread, you can explicitly create a single thread scheduler to replace `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`:

```
val singleThreadScheduler = Schedulers.single()
```

Even if the events are emitted on other threads, you can ensure you process them only on your single thread using `observeOn`:

```
subject.mergeWith(subject1)
   .observeOn(singleThreadScheduler)
   .scan(
         getInitState(),
         {state, event ->
           // state update here 
         }
     )
    .subscribe({state ->
      // use state here
    })
```

The difference between `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` can be pretty confusing, and logging the thread id can be useful to check everything is running on the thread you expect.

> http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working one for sure. But what would I do without scheduler? For example if I try to use same approach in JavaScript?

Comment: not familiar with rx-js, but I would guess it is single threaded anyway. Certainly I would expect any js library to be single threaded by default.